# Using a non-repeating frame on the second page of a report

Tags: oracle, frames, oraclereports

I have an Oracle 10g report that is not functioning properly.  I have three repeating frames and one non-repeating frame in the lowest repeating frame with my data elements in it.  My issue is that when I have this non-repeating frame on the first page in the layout it works just fine, but, when I slide that frame down with all of the data elements to the second page in the layout it does not work. To reiterate that is all I do, no properties are changed or data elements added or removed, just all current elements slid down to the second page of the layout.

This shows you what I am talking about

[image: Error]

Here is the error message

> Terminated with error: `<br>` REP-1814: Report cannot be formatted. Object
>   'vertically' can never fit within 'M_DEFAULT_MR_LETTER'.

and this shows you how I have the report and static fame properties set

[image: Form]

I am hoping that will give you enough information to see if you can tell me what I need to do to fix it.

Comment: I added the images and changed your title to make it less generic and hopefully encourage more people to come and look.

Answer (score 1):

Change the value of frame: M_DEFAULT_MR_LETTER

Old Value:
Advanced Layout => Print Object On => All Pages

New Value:
Advanced Layout => Print Object On => First Page

Answer (score 0):

with Print Object On => First Page

also you will need vertical elasticity - > variable